# Netbeans - Expected : but found if (link.style.animation)

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code which controls my hamburger menu.
Everything works fine in brackets but I am getting errors in Netbeans.

```js
function navSlide() {
var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
        var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li');
        //Toggle Nav
        burger.onclick = function () {
        menu.classList.toggle('nav-active');
                //Animate links
                links.forEach((link, index) = > {
                if (link.style.animation)
                {link.style.animation = '';
                } else{
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + .3}s`;
                }
                });
                //burger animation
                burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
        }
}
navSlide();
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Sorry it should be visible now

Comment: ` links.forEach((link, index) = > {` the `= >` should be `=>`

Comment: Thank you that fixed one of the errors but I still seem to have some errors in the if else statement. Expected : but found (if(link.style.animation)

Comment: Does it have some more info there ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.